# Generating namespaced XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to add more claims to the ClaimTypesOffered element as shown below:

```
<fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
  <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
    <auth:DisplayName>Name</auth:DisplayName>
    <auth:Description>The name of the subject.</auth:Description>
  </auth:ClaimType>
</fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
```

There is a lot of namespace magic going on there and I am trying to work my way through it.  Just getting the proper element name has been difficult.  I have tried all of the following:

```
new XElement(XNamespace.Get("auth") + "ClaimType", "somedata");
```

gives

```
<ClaimType xmlns="auth">somedata</ClaimType>
```

**and**

```
new XElement(XName.Get("{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706}auth"), "somedata");
```

gives

```
<auth xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">somedata</auth>
```

**and**

```
new XElement("auth:ClaimType", "somedata");
```

gives

```
System.Xml.XmlException : The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

I'm looking for help getting this further along, a full example of generating the claim including the attributes and inner elements would be awesome, even a small push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Try a search on [so] for [`[xml-namespaces][linq-to-xml]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-namespaces+linq-to-xml)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747304/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-generate-an-xdocument-using-the-short-prefix-instead-of

Comment: @JohnSaunders Posting that implies that there are existing answers to questions similar to mine.  I searched for existing answers and found very little related to generating XML with namespaces.  For me this response is essentially equivalent to "google it".

Comment: I've just got through reading them and found several that are either outright answers, or else can teach you what the answer is. That's a pretty specific search, and only brings up 23 results. Furthermore, it's an answer that shows you how to search for combinations of tags - that's a very useful tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is defining the namespace on the parent element, then the child elements can use that namespace.  Without the *new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "auth", auth.NamespaceName)* the namespace is defined in the other ways as seen in the original question.

```
        XNamespace fed = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706";
        XNamespace auth = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706";

        XElement root = new XElement(auth + "ClaimType",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "auth", auth.NamespaceName),
            new XAttribute("Uri", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"),
            new XAttribute("Optional", "true"),
            new XElement(auth+"DisplayName", "EmployeeID"),
            new XElement(auth+"Description", "The employee's designated ID number.")
        );

        Console.WriteLine(root);
```